# 2017 Hyundai Elantra crank no start

Tags: starting, ignition, crank

Completed an engine swap due to a rod knock. Can read all sensors with Solus. I have crank sensor rpm and injector pulse. I have no spark. I check for power at the coils and it is a 3 wire connector. It has 12 volt, ground and another 12 volt, no pulse or spark that I can see. I also have no trottle TPS response. It moves at key on and stops. It shows 6.5 volt as should for closed. I have good APS reading 0 to 99.6. But no trottle plates movement. The car drove in and now has no start. I changed over all the sensors from old motor to see if a sensor was the concern. No luck. Stumped.

Comment: Is this one of those rare Hyundai models that came with immobilizer? If the engine swap included all the electronics and you're not using the key that the replacement engine expects, the ignition will be disabled.

Comment: Have you read the ECU error codes?